# how to call An Activity class from a noraml java class in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have one noraml java class say ReceivedChat.java in the constructor of this class i want to call an Activity of Android.

```
public class ReceivedChat {
    String message;
    String from;
    Context context;

    ReceivedChat(String message, String from) {
        this.message = message;
        this.from = from;

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("message", this.message);
        b.putString("from", this.from);
        b.putString("fromChat", "true");

        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), XmppChatActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(b);
        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

My Activity class is `XmppChatActivity`.

This program is not working. it is not calling the onCreate of my `XmppChatActivity` class
Any help will be thankfull to me.

Comment: where you initialize `context` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> how to call An Activity class from a normal java class

you will need to pass Current Activity Context to `ReceivedChat` at the time of Object Creation from an Activity or any other Application Components as :

```
ReceivedChat(String message, String from,Context context)
{
this.message = message;
this.from = from;
this.context=context;  //<< initialize Context here 
Intent i = new Intent(context,XmppChatActivity.class);
 //....your code here
context.startActivity(i);

}
```

and instead of starting another Activity from class Constructor  create an method in `ReceivedChat` and call it after object creation

Comment: ReceivedChat constructor is getting called from JNI, i do not have context there. so i can not pass context.

Comment: @user2139898 : then change your code logic  by using singleton class like  `Application Class to get Application context inside ReceivedChat class without latest context of Activity to Application it's not possible to start an Activity

Comment: In case of singelton class i can not call its constructor from JNI.Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: @user2139898 : checkout [this example](http://uquery.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-get-application-context.html) for getting context from Application class maybe help u in solving current issue

Comment: Thanks. it is usefull. now i can acheive my task. very very thanks to you.

Comment: Thanks for help. i have one another issue in Android. I want to play a Video file in Android. i can play it with path or URi of the file. but i am getting the file content through a protocol, i do not have the url or uri of the file. I am getting the content , so i want to know how can i plat these content. i heared it in some way we can store the content and then make the URI. if you knao any thing regarding the same. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @user2139898 : best way is make an new question for other issue friend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135082/play-the-video-content-in-android-without-having-uri-and-path-to-file "question is already there, but no Answer"